# Помощь по Discord Node JS

Tags: node.js, discord

Как реализовать подобное в видео https://youtu.be/A2415wZ2XaU , но только на Node JS? При этом, задача стоит публиковать в определенный канал ответы из Гугл формы.

Comment: Также, только на node.js. Опишите, что конкретно реализовать. В каком виде. Как. Приложите вашу попытку.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы код написали за вас?